# Looping through REST API calls improperly breaks at first iteration or last iteration

Tags: loops, rest, google-apps-script, do-while

I am trying to send a **REST API** call to retrieve a lot of data. Now this data is returned in JSON format and is **limited to 2000 records** each call. However, if there are more than 2000 records then there is a key called `nextRecordsUrl` with a link to an endPoint with the next 2000 records.

And this pattern continues until there are less than 2000 records in a single call and then `nextRecordsUrl` is undefined.

I have this loop that essentially pushes the data to an array and then calls the endpoint listed in the `nextRecordsUrl` key.

```
    do {
      for (var i in arrLeads.records) {
        let data = arrLeads.records[i];
        let createDate = new GMT(data.CreatedDate, "dd-MM-YYYY");
        let fAssocDate = new GMT(data['First_Campaign_assoc_date__c'],"dd-MM-YYYY");
        let lAssocDate = new GMT(data['Last_Campaign_assoc_date__c'], "dd-MM-YYYY");
        let convDate = new GMT(data.ConvertedDate, "dd-MM-YYYY");
        leads.push([data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.Id, data.Email, data.Title, data['hs_contact_id__c'], createDate, data.Company, data.OwnerId, data.Country, data['Region_by_manager__c'], data.Status, data.Industry, data['Reason_for_Disqualifying_Nurture__c'], data['Reason_for_Disqualifying_Dead__c'], data['Lead_Type__c'], data['First_Campaign_Name__c'], data['First_CampaignType__c'], fAssocDate, data['Last_Campaign_Name__c'], lAssocDate, data['Last_Campaign_Type__c'], convDate, data.ConvertedAccountId, data.ConvertedContactId, data.ConvertedOpportunityId]);
      }

      var arrLeads = getQueryWithFullEndPoint(arrLeads.nextRecordsUrl);
    } while (arrLeads.nextRecordsUrl != null && arrLeads.nextRecordsUrl != undefined);
```

I used to use the regular **while** loop, but it caused obvious problems in that it wouldn't run at all if the initial call had an empty `nextRecordsUrl` field.

But this also has an issue. While the first iteration works well, the last one does not because it makes the call on the next iteration before the loop checks the `nextRecordsUrl` field.

So essentially, it will loop through all the records normally. But when it gets to the last one, it has already run the last endPoint and will break the loop, because now the '`nextRecordsUrl` key is empty. So the last iteration will be ignored.

I thought of moving the call to after the check, right after the `do {`, but that will cause problems for the first iteration.

I also thought about duplicating the `for` loop after the `do`, but I prefer a cleaner solution that doesn't involve duplicating code.

So how do I write this code in a way that takes into account the first iteration, even if there no second iteration and the last iteration, where it has records but has an empty `nextRecordsUrl`, without having to double up the code?

Comment: It could be done by setting up a ```while (true)``` loop with a conditional statement that breaks the loop if the ```nextRecordsUrl``` key is **null**. It could also be achieved via other logic such as a **do while loop** or similar. The only thing is that the first call (and the logic around it) will have to be different since you don't have a ```nextRecordsUrl``` key yet. Did I understand your issue correctly?

Comment: @OriolCastander, yes. The issue with the **do while loop** is that the last call will break before it has time to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this with a small tweak in the code.

My issue is that I getting the next batch before I could test the original, and so I was always 1 batch short.

The solutions was actually to define a variable at the beginning of each loop `arrLeadsNext = arrLeads.nextRecordsUrl;`

and have the while statement check this variable.

So it looks like this:

```
 do {
      var arrLeadsNext = arrLeads.nextRecordsUrl;
      for (var i in arrLeads.records) {
        let data = arrLeads.records[i];
        let createDate = new GMT(data.CreatedDate, "dd-MM-YYYY").process();
        let fAssocDate = new GMT(data['First_Campaign_assoc_date__c'], "dd-MM-YYYY").process();
        let lAssocDate = new GMT(data['Last_Campaign_assoc_date__c'], "dd-MM-YYYY").process();
        let convDate = new GMT(data.ConvertedDate, "dd-MM-YYYY").process();
        leads.push([data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.Id, data.Email, data.Title, data['hs_contact_id__c'], createDate, data.Company, data.OwnerId, data.Country, data['Region_by_manager__c'], data.Status, data.Industry, data['Reason_for_Disqualifying_Nurture__c'], data['Reason_for_Disqualifying_Dead__c'], data['Lead_Type__c'], data['First_Campaign_Name__c'], data['First_CampaignType__c'], fAssocDate, data['Last_Campaign_Name__c'], lAssocDate, data['Last_Campaign_Type__c'], convDate, data.ConvertedAccountId, data.ConvertedContactId, data.ConvertedOpportunityId]);
      }

      var arrLeads = (arrLeadsNext != null) ? getQueryWithFullEndPoint(arrLeadsNext) : '';
    } while (arrLeadsNext != null && arrLeadsNext != undefined);
```

So the check at the end hasn't been changed by the next API call for the next batch as it will only change once the next iteration of the loop begins.